# AJAX button not firing asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am using search for products with AJAX but i have pagging code for products with on `click` function , but the on click function inside `ShopAjaxSearch.aspx` not firing after the result come back.

**ShopAjax.aspx :**

```
<div id="demo-2">
    <input type="search" placeholder="Search" onchange="this.value='';" id="txtBrand">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#txtBrand').keyup(function() {

            var param = {
                "str": $(this).val()
            };
            $.ajax({
                url: "ShopAjaxSearch.aspx",
                data: param,
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#result').html(data);

                },
                error: function() {
                    alert('Error');
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="result">

</div>
```

**ShopAjaxSearch :**

```
<div class="pagging">
    <asp:DataList ID="dlPaging" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" OnItemCommand="dlPaging_ItemCommand" OnItemDataBound="dlPaging_ItemDataBound" CssClass="pagenumON">
        <ItemTemplate>

            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnPaging" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("PageIndex") %>' CommandName="Paging" Text='<%# Eval("PageText") %>' CssClass="pagenum"></asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>

    <asp:Label id="lblPageInfo" runat="server" ForeColor="Red"> </asp:Label>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnPrevious" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" OnClick="lbtnPrevious_Click" CssClass="button prev">Previous</asp:LinkButton>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnNext" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" OnClick="lbtnNext_Click" CssClass="button next">Next</asp:LinkButton>

    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnFirst" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" OnClick="lbtnFirst_Click" CssClass="button prev">First</asp:LinkButton>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnLast" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" OnClick="lbtnLast_Click" CssClass="button next">Last</asp:LinkButton>

</div>
```

The link buttons `Next,Previous,First,Last` Not firing in **ShopAjax.aspx**

Please Help Thank You !!

Answer (score 0):

The paging buttons on the search page are suppose to invoke a postback to itself  (ShopAjaxSearch) and handle paging on the server side.   But if it posts back at all it would actually post to the ShopAjax page and the target events would not exist.

In your scenario, the easiest solution may just be an asp update panel so that you can utilize paging that is already build into some of the WebForm controls

Comment: Where exactly to use the update panel i tried to use it in the 2 pages and didnt work. Can you please give me working code. Thank You!

Comment: First create a single WebForm page with what your trying to accomplish.  Once you have that working then put an asp:updatepanel around the content you want to refresh with AJAX.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/816953/How-To-Implement-Paging-in-GridView-Control-in-ASP

Comment: Worked by changing linkbutton to Button but it keep redirect to Ajax Page (AjaxShopSearch)